# Raspberry Pi remote control. Cannot log in as root user

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, remote

I am newbie and have a question regarding Raspberry Pi Remote.

I configured successfully the Raspberry Pi for remote. If I want to login with the root user, a bluescreen appears. I know there is a solution to create a second user to login. This works. But with the second user I do not have the permissions as the root user

I switch always with su - rootuser but this is annoying and in many cases it prevents me in working.

Is there any other solution to login with the root user?

I did not find.

Comment: What does "I configured successfully the raspberry Pi for remote" mean? What exactly are you trying to do? Raspberry Pi OS **does NOT** have a root user.

Comment: @JaromandaX we have had this conversation before. It does not have a root **USER** although it has a root account and the normal use of Debian allows use of the root account with `sudo`. The OP stated "I want to login with the root user" which I am sure will agree is not possible (by default) - and certainly not as "remote" (whatever the OP means by this).

Comment: Sorry @Milliways - I remember now (I'm cold and there's wolves after me - Simpsons reference to being old :p), I'll remove that comment

Comment: @JaromandaX I an sure we are in total agreement about this - the OP (like many new users) does not understand the concept - so my comments are simplified (hopefully to help).

Comment: @Milliways - totally agree that there is never a good reason to "login as root"

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the `su` command with elevated privilegies.

The command ; `sudo su -` will give you a root shell.

But this is **highly discouraged** use `sudo` when you want to execute a command with elevated privilegies.

Reading about differences between sudo and su: https://monovm.com/blog/su-vs-sudo/